# Unclosed Objects Alerts in CheckMarx scan

Tags: java, security, java-8, owasp, checkmarx

I have run SAST in my codebase and got some Medium severity alerts in the Checkmarx scan and few of them states 'Unclosed_Objects' . I am not understanding this issue. Any pointers will help me.
This is giving alerts in this section of the code. All the close() methods.

```
public Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            // use serialization to create a deep copy
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(value);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            bos.close();

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            Object obj = new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();
            bais.close();
            return obj;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
            throw new HibernateException(ex);
        }
```

Comment: The object created with `new ObjectInputStream(bais)` is never closed. It’s irrelevant here, as the array based streams hold no resources at all, but in general, you should use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of calling `close` manually.

Comment: Thnx Holger..using the try with resources didnt give any checkmarx issue